# Truncate 206k+ rows from table PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, large-data

I'm trying to truncate 206,686 rows (exactly) from a table using Postgres. I'm looking for the most effective way to do so, using truncate query - I had it running for 3 hours this morning and with no luck, it still was "running" and no rows were truncated at all.

What's the best way to truncate large amounts of data in excess of 200k+?

Query displaying count:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM <removed>;
```

Output: count = 206686

There is no locks in place currently:

```
blocked_pid | blocked_user | blocking_pid | blocking_user | blocked_statement | current_statement_in_blocking_process 
-------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [postgres truncate is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936204/postgres-truncate-is-slow)

Comment: What command did you initally run? Are their foreign keys referencing this table?

Comment: 206k rows is not that large of a data set in postgres.   Most likely a lock somewhere

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any locks in place

Comment: You cannot truncate a given set of rows (did you mean DELETE?), you can only truncate an entire table, which means: after truncation there will be zero rows left in the table.

Comment: @joop which is exactly what I want and need to do - truncate every single row in the table.

Comment: Any index and foreign key ? What happens if you use "delete from" ?

Comment: There is a difference between `TRUNCATE xxx;` and `DELETE FROM xxx;` In the DELETE case triggers (if present) will be executed, in the TRUNCATE case not. Both (eventually) need exclusive access to the table. And in both cases FK references to the xxx table could prevent the operation.

Comment: Have you tried to delete them in chunks? Repeatedly `DELETE FROM table WHERE id < N * 1000` in cycle from `N=1` to `max(id)/1000+1`

Comment: Is your problem solved ?

Comment: Please show `explain [my query here]`