# Foreign Key constraint issues using sequel and database cleaner

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sequel, database-cleaner

I am running into issues using [database cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) with [sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) and sqlite foreign key constraints. Specifically, I am using the `:truncation` strategy with Capybara integration tests.

For the given sample schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE events(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT);

CREATE TABLE events_users(
  user_id INTEGER,
  event_id INTEGER,

  FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(event_id) REFERENCES events(id)
);
```

And sequel models:

```ruby
class User < Sequel::Model
  many_to_many :events
end

class Event < Sequel::Model
  many_to_many :users
end
```

Running the following:

```
# normally this would be run in
# an rspec before(:each) for my :feature specs
DatabaseCleaner.start
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

bob = User.create(name: "bob")
sally = User.create(name: "sally")
event = Event.create(title: "Everyone's invited")
event.users << [bob, sally]

DatabaseCleaner.clean
```

Results in an error

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (Sequel::ForeignKeyConstraintViolation)
```

I can get around this by altering my before statement to disable the foreign_keys PRAGMA:

```
DB.foreign_keys = false
DatabaseCleaner.start
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
```

(or not using FOREIGN KEY in my tables), but that seems wrong since I want the benefits that foreign keys constraints — or at least I think I do ;).

Is this a fundamental misunderstanding of how to use foreign key constraints, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been almost two years and I've given up attempting to solve this cleanly T_T.

I experienced random `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed` issues during a recent `sequel` upgrade. To resolve this, I switched from `DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation` to `DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :deletion`.

There's been a [thorough analysis of the benefits/costs of `:truncate` versus `:delete`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11423886/1048479) and the answer (at least for postgres) is *it depends*. So far `:delete` seems to be a little faster for my small testing data set.