# Truncating all tables in a Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, truncate, database-table

I regularly need to delete all the data from my PostgreSQL database before a rebuild. How would I do this directly in SQL?

At the moment I've managed to come up with a SQL statement that returns all the commands I need to execute:

```
SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' ||  tablename || ';' FROM pg_tables WHERE tableowner='MYUSER';
```

But I can't see a way to execute them programmatically once I have them.

Answer (score 304, accepted):

FrustratedWithFormsDesigner is correct, PL/pgSQL can do this. Here's the script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION truncate_tables(username IN VARCHAR) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    statements CURSOR FOR
        SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables
        WHERE tableowner = username AND schemaname = 'public';
BEGIN
    FOR stmt IN statements LOOP
        EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || quote_ident(stmt.tablename) || ' CASCADE;';
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This creates a stored function (you need to do this just once) which you can afterwards use like this:

```
SELECT truncate_tables('MYUSER');
```

Comment: Had to rejig a little but after that it worked like a charm! I've never used plpgsql before so this would've taken me ages. Thanks!

For anyone that needs it I've added the code I ended up using to the bottom of this post.

Comment: Sorry, I was probably thinking in Oracle PL/SQL :( I fixed the syntax error in my code above.

Comment: you can also move the SELECT statement directly to FOR loop.  `DECLARE r RECORD;` then for loop:  `FOR r IN SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables LOOP`

Comment: I would add CASCADE to TRUNCATE TABLE

Comment: In fact, to truncate ALL tables, the CASCADE clause is required!

Comment: Just remember that you need to restart your sequences (auto increment) or your new data will start with the previous max id number...

Comment: @Henning I realize this is an older question, but would adding `RESTART IDENTITY` be a good addition to the query?

Comment: OMG!! I just truncated all my tables in "public" schema.... pls add another parameter of "schema" so that the function truncates tables only on the schema that is provided!

Comment: @roneo see the question: `ALL TABLES` in a database!

Comment: where to mention database name?

Answer (score 130):

Explicit cursors are rarely needed in PL/pgSQL. Use the simpler and faster **implicit cursor** of a [**`FOR`** loop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING):

Since table names are not unique per database, you have to schema-qualify table names to be sure. Also, I limit the function to the default schema 'public'. Adapt to your needs, but be sure to exclude the system schemas `pg_*` and `information_schema`.

Be **very careful** with these functions. They nuke your database. I added a child safety device. Comment the `RAISE NOTICE` line and uncomment `EXECUTE` to prime the bomb ...

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_truncate_tables(_username text)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _tbl text;
   _sch text;
BEGIN
   FOR _sch, _tbl IN 
      SELECT schemaname, tablename
      FROM   pg_tables
      WHERE  tableowner = _username
      AND    schemaname = 'public'
   LOOP
      -- dangerous, test before you execute!
      RAISE NOTICE '%',  -- once confident, comment this line ...
      -- EXECUTE         -- ... and uncomment this one
         format('TRUNCATE TABLE %I.%I CASCADE', _sch, _tbl);
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

[`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) requires Postgres 9.1 or later. In older versions concatenate the query string like this:

```
'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || quote_ident(_sch) || '.' || quote_ident(_tbl)  || ' CASCADE';
```

#### Single command, no loop

Since we can [**`TRUNCATE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html) multiple tables at once we don't need any cursor or loop at all:

- [Passing table names in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723851/passing-table-names-in-an-array/23729229#23729229)

Aggregate all table names and execute a single statement. Simpler, faster:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_truncate_tables(_username text)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   -- dangerous, test before you execute!
   RAISE NOTICE '%',  -- once confident, comment this line ...
   -- EXECUTE         -- ... and uncomment this one
  (SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE '
       || string_agg(format('%I.%I', schemaname, tablename), ', ')
       || ' CASCADE'
   FROM   pg_tables
   WHERE  tableowner = _username
   AND    schemaname = 'public'
   );
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT truncate_tables('postgres');
```

#### Refined query

You don't even need a function. In Postgres 9.0+ you can execute dynamic commands in a [**`DO`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) statement. And in Postgres 9.5+ the syntax can be even simpler:

```sql
DO
$do$
BEGIN
   -- dangerous, test before you execute!
   RAISE NOTICE '%',  -- once confident, comment this line ...
   -- EXECUTE         -- ... and uncomment this one
   (SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || string_agg(oid::regclass::text, ', ') || ' CASCADE'
    FROM   pg_class
    WHERE  relkind = 'r'  -- only tables
    AND    relnamespace = 'public'::regnamespace
   );
END
$do$;
```

About the difference between `pg_class`, `pg_tables` and `information_schema.tables`:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

About `regclass` and quoted table names:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

### For repeated use

Create a **"template" database** (let's name it `my_template`) with your vanilla structure and all empty tables. Then go through a **`DROP` / [`CREATE DATABASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html)** cycle:

```
DROP DATABASE mydb;
CREATE DATABASE mydb TEMPLATE my_template;
```

This is ***extremely* fast**, because Postgres copies the whole structure on the file level. No concurrency issues or other overhead slowing you down.

If concurrent connections keep you from dropping the DB, consider:

- [Force drop db while others may be connected](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/11895/3684)

Comment: It's worth noting that this last function wiped ALL databases. Not just the currently connected one.... yeah...  call me naiive but that really wasn't clear from this post.

Comment: @Amalgovinus: Which last function? None of the functions in my answer touch anything outside the *current* database (except for `DROP DATABASE mydb`, obviously). Are you confusing *schemas* with databases, maybe?

Comment: The very last one with DO $func$. I used the same schema name in two different databases, so it looks like my data was dropped from both. so yes, I was confusing those two

Comment: @Amalgovinus: No, that's impossible. The `DO` command (like any other SQL statement) is executed in the current database *exclusively*. Postgres has no way to access other databases in the same transaction. You would have to use dblink or FDW to do that. But it *does* affect all schemas in the current database - unless you add `WHERE  t.schemaname = 'public'` to restrict the effect to one particular schema in this particular case.

Comment: Really nice to know about those templates. This can me useful even in automated tests scenarios, where a database reset/preparation may be needed.

Comment: I fixed your refined query, it had a wayward extra semicolon that my postgres choked on.
`ERROR: mismatched parentheses at or near ";" LINE 8: ... AND relnamespace = 'public'::regnamespace;`

Comment: Thanks for great answer, I'm using "Single command, no loop" which returns the TRUNCATE command, how should I go about executing it?

Comment: @Mahyar i was confused by this at first too, comment the RAISE line and uncomment the EXECUTE one.

Comment: In your `Refined query` example, why is `EXECUTE` commented out? I can't seem to get that method to work. Without the `EXECUTE` it just makes a string of the `TRUNCATE TABLE ...` command but doesn't run it. Uncommenting the `EXECUTE` results in `syntax error at or near "SELECT"`. I ended up having to delete the `RAISE NOTICE` line, and uncomment `EXECUTE` to get it to run.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike: You may have missed the note at the top: `Be very careful with these functions. They nuke your database. I added a child safety device. Comment the RAISE NOTICE line and uncomment EXECUTE to prime the bomb ...`

Comment: the suggested queue is full, but @ErwinBrandstetter you should take a look at them. in your last edit you deleted the vital `LOOP` keyword in the main answer

Comment: @SampsonCrowley: Thanks for pointing out! I fixed the collateral damage from my previous edit.

Answer (score 54):

If I have to do this, I will simply create a schema sql of current db, then drop & create db, then load db with schema sql.

Below are the steps involved:

1) Create Schema dump of database (`--schema-only`)

`pg_dump mydb -s > schema.sql`

2) Drop database

`drop database mydb;`

3) Create Database

`create database mydb;`

4) Import Schema

`psql mydb < schema.sql`

Answer (score 30):

Just execute the query bellow:

```
DO $$ DECLARE
    r RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN (SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = current_schema()) LOOP
        EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || quote_ident(r.tablename) || '';
    END LOOP;
END $$;
```

Comment: I have tried many other solutions but only this one works.

Comment: I had foreign key constraint in few tables in schema on line number 5.

EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || quote_ident(r.tablename) || ' cascade';

Comment: Simple is best 

Comment: DO $$ DECLARE
    r RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN (SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = current_schema()) LOOP
        EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || quote_ident(r.tablename) || ' CASCADE';
    END LOOP;
END $$;

// use this for CASCADE

Comment: is there any way to run this like psql database_name -c ( command) because it give errors when I try. Query works when I login into database and paste it but I would love to run it without going into database

Answer (score 10):

In this case it would probably be better to just have an empty database that you use as a template and when you need to refresh, drop the existing database and create a new one from the template.

Answer (score 7):

One thing that I don't see here is truncating and then resetting sequences. Note that a simple truncate like all that have been given here will just truncate the tables, but will leave sequences at their pre-truncate values. To reset the sequences to their start values when you truncate do:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;
```

you can just add that RESTART IDENTITY to any of the answers you fancy, no need to repeat that here. CASCADE is there for any foreign key constraints you may face.

Answer (score 7):

Simply, you can run this piece of SQL :

```
DO $$ DECLARE
  r RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname =current_schema()) LOOP
    EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || quote_ident(r.tablename) || ' CASCADE';
  END LOOP;
END $$;
```

Answer (score 5):

Guys the better and clean way is to :

1) Create Schema dump of database (--schema-only)
pg_dump mydb -s > schema.sql

2) Drop database
drop database mydb;

3) Create Database
create database mydb;

4) Import Schema
psql mydb < schema.sql

It´s work for me!

Have a nice day.
Hiram Walker

Answer (score 4):

Cleaning `AUTO_INCREMENT` version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION truncate_tables(username IN VARCHAR) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    statements CURSOR FOR
        SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables
        WHERE tableowner = username AND schemaname = 'public';
BEGIN
    FOR stmt IN statements LOOP
        EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || quote_ident(stmt.tablename) || ' CASCADE;';

        IF EXISTS (
            SELECT column_name 
            FROM information_schema.columns 
            WHERE table_name=quote_ident(stmt.tablename) and column_name='id'
        ) THEN
           EXECUTE 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' || quote_ident(stmt.tablename) || '_id_seq RESTART WITH 1';
        END IF;

    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you use dynamic SQL to execute each statement in turn? You would probably have to write a PL/pgSQL script to do this.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html (section 38.5.4. Executing Dynamic Commands)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with bash also:

```
#!/bin/bash
PGPASSWORD='' psql -h 127.0.0.1 -Upostgres sng --tuples-only --command "SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || schemaname || '.' ||  tablename || ';' FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname in ('cms_test', 'ids_test', 'logs_test', 'sps_test');" | 
tr "\\n" " " | 
xargs -I{} psql -h 127.0.0.1 -Upostgres sng --command "{}"
```

You will need to adjust schema names, passwords and usernames to match your schemas.

Answer (score 2):

For removing the data and preserving the table-structures in [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) you can do:

- Right-click database -> backup, select "Schema only"
- Drop the database
- Create a new database and name it like the former
- Right-click the new database -> restore -> select the backup, select "Schema only"

Answer (score 2):

If you can use [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) you can use `\gexec` meta command to execute query output;

```
SELECT
    format('TRUNCATE TABLE %I.%I', ns.nspname, c.relname)
  FROM pg_namespace ns 
  JOIN pg_class c ON ns.oid = c.relnamespace
  JOIN pg_roles r ON r.oid = c.relowner
  WHERE
    ns.nspname = 'table schema' AND                               -- add table schema criteria 
    r.rolname = 'table owner' AND                                 -- add table owner criteria
    ns.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') AND    -- exclude system schemas
    c.relkind = 'r' AND                                           -- tables only
    has_table_privilege(c.oid, 'TRUNCATE')                        -- check current user has truncate privilege
  \gexec
```

Note that `\gexec` is introduced into the version 9.6

Answer (score -2):

You can use something like this to get all truncate queries.

```
SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' ||  table_name || ';' 
  FROM information_schema.tables
 WHERE table_schema='schema_name'
   AND table_type='BASE TABLE';
```