# Creating a view of frequencies from a table with unknown number of columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with n columns and I need to create a view which contains the frequencies of every unique value in every column. n is unknown since, I need to apply the solution on numerous tables with different number of columns.

For example i have table:

```
column1  column2  column3
value1   value2   value3
value2   value2   value1
value1   value2   value2
```

The view should be something like this:

```
columnname    value    frequency

 column1      value1    2
 column1      value2    1
 column2      value2    3
```

...

Since I have very little experience with sql any help would be extremely appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Thus far I have come up with this but am sort of stonewalled now.

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION create_view () RETURNS setof record AS $$
DECLARE   
col RECORD;
BEGIN
for col in execute 'select column_name from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = ''table123''' LOOP
    ???
END LOOP;
return;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Simple SQL:

```
SELECT 'col1' AS col, col1 AS val, count(*) AS ct FROM  tbl GROUP BY col1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'col2', col2, count(*) FROM  tbl GROUP BY col2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'col3', col3, count(*) FROM  tbl GROUP BY col3
```

#### PL/pqSQL function executing dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_demo(_schema text, _tbl text)
  RETURNS TABLE(col text, val text, ct bigint) AS
$xx$
DECLARE   
   _fld text;
   _sql text := '';
BEGIN

FOR _fld IN  
   SELECT a.attname          -- use quote_ident to safeguard against SQLi
   FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
   WHERE  a.attrelid =  (COALESCE(_schema || '.', '') || _tbl)::regclass
   AND    a.attnum > 0
   AND    NOT a.attisdropped
-- AND    a.attname ~~ '%col%'   -- if you want to pick specific columns
LOOP
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
  'SELECT $1, ' || quote_ident(_fld) || '::text, count(*)
   FROM ' || COALESCE(quote_ident(_schema) || '.', '') || quote_ident(_tbl) || '
   GROUP BY 2'
   USING _fld;
END LOOP;

END;
$xx$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_demo('public', 'mytable');
```

Or, if you want to use the schema provided by search_path:

```
SELECT * FROM f_demo(NULL, 'mytable');
```

#### Major points

- Works for **any table** and **any number of columns** with **values of any type**.
- Values are cast to text to simplify my example. Could be done with a polymorphic type, too.
- See this related answer for info on plpgsql techniques and links: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8146245/939860