# PostgreSQL execute + date

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I am trying to create an SQL select statement in PL/pgSQL procedure. It was all fine until I had to add a `date` to the select. The problem is that to compare dates in select clause my date must be enclosed in single quotes `''` (e.g. '01.01.2011'), but in my case it is already a `text` type and I can't add it there.

Below is a sample code that should have same problem:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sample(i_date timestamp without time zone)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  _count integer := 0;
  _sql text := '';
BEGIN

  IF i_date IS NOT NULL THEN
   _cond := _cond || ' AND t.created>' || i_date;
END IF;

_sql := 'SELECT count(*) FROM test t WHERE 1=1' || _cond;

EXECUTE _sql INTO _count;
RETURN _count;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Is there any other way to "escape" date? Or some other suggestions?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, do you mean that t.created in your example is varchar in the database?

Comment: No, it is date. But if i_date does not have '' around it then it is doing arithmetical equation not comparing two dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use insert *values* safely and efficiently into a dynamically build and executed SQL string, there are a number of possibilities. The best one is to use the [USING clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sample(_date timestamp without time zone)
RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE '
    SELECT count(*)::int
    FROM   test t
    WHERE  t.created > $1'
    USING  _date;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

This is actually a bad example, because it could be simplified to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sample(_date timestamp)
RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
    SELECT count(*)::int
    FROM   test
    WHERE  created > $1;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Another way would be to use [`quote_literal()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER).
I wrote more about [dynamic SQL in plpgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8146245/939860) here.

Comment: Thanks Erwin!
quote_literal() is perfect for me.