# Spring boot pagination with native query throws NumberFormatException

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

The error started to show up when I added pagination (using `Pageable`) to the search query with `ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}`. I'm using H2 database for unit-testing with `database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect`.

Spring boot version: `1.5.9.RELEASE`
Java version: `1.8`

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface VacancyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Vacancy, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM vacancies WHERE location ILIKE %:location% AND CONCAT(title, ' ', description) ILIKE %:keyword% ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}",
            countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vacancies WHERE location ILIKE %:location% AND CONCAT(title, ' ', description) ILIKE %:keyword%",
            nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Vacancy> search(@Param("location") String location, @Param("keyword") String keyword, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Controller method (controller is prefixed with `/vacancy/`):

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/search/location/{location}/keyword/{keyword}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Page<Vacancy>> search(@PathVariable String location, @PathVariable String keyword, Pageable pageable) {
    Page<Vacancy> vacancies = vacancyRepository.search(location, keyword, pageable);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(vacancies);
}
```

How it is used in tests:

```
    // Given
    String path = "/vacancy/search/location/searchQueryLocation/keyword/search?page=0&size=1&sort=id";

    // When
    ResultActions sendRequest = mvc.perform(get(path));
```

Exception thrown:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not extract ResultSet

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:160)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)
    at uk.gov.cshr.vcm.controller.VacancyControllerTest.testSearch(VacancyControllerTest.java:336)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper$1.runTestMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:205)
    at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.run(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:175)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:217)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:641)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:282)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:503)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:209)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.search(Unknown Source)
    at uk.gov.cshr.vcm.controller.VacancyController.search(VacancyController.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2117)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1967)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:322)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:188)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:499)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:477)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Data conversion error converting "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"; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM vacancies WHERE location ILIKE ? AND CONCAT(title, ' ', description) ILIKE ? ORDER BY ?, id asc limit ? [22018-196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:996)
    at org.h2.value.Value.getInt(Value.java:459)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.prepareOrder(Query.java:518)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.prepare(Select.java:834)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.recompileIfRequired(CommandContainer.java:88)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:109)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:201)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy124.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "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"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:592)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:641)
```

Judging by the "aced" in the beginnig, it looks like a serialized Java object, but I don't see where it is serialized.

Generated Hibernate log:

```
Hibernate: SELECT * FROM vacancies WHERE location ILIKE ? AND CONCAT(title, ' ', description) ILIKE ? ORDER BY ?, id asc limit ?
2018-01-04 15:08:02.940  WARN 6872 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 22018, SQLState: 22018
2018-01-04 15:08:02.940 ERROR 6872 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Data conversion error converting "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"; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM vacancies WHERE location ILIKE ? AND CONCAT(title, ' ', description) ILIKE ? ORDER BY ?, id asc limit ? [22018-196]
```

The same query without `Pageable` works as expected. I tried different ways of writing the same `Pageable` thing (including `ORDER BY /*#pageable*/` or `ORDER BY t.id DESC \n-- #pageable\n` or by trying to comment the `#pageable` in the query (`/*#pageable*/`) and passing my own page and page size parameters) but nothing works.

I know that I can replace this particular query with somethig that uses `to_upper()` instead of `ILIKE` and use JPA queries, but the following steps will imply something that is not implemented in JPA queries and requires native queries.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add a bit more to the stacktrace ? Would be good to see what bit of code further up is throwing the exception.

Comment: Added more stack trace to the question. I don't have a direct test for the repository yet, I will try it and uptade the question.

Comment: Ta.I think the stack trace is good enough to work off.

Comment: @PaulNUK I tested the method directly with `Page<Vacancy> search = vacancyRepository.search("searchQueryLocation", "search", new PageRequest(0, 1));` and, to my regret, it yields exactly the same exception (without the "request" stack trace level, obviously).
I will also update the question with hibernate's log.

Comment: This may be of use https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/402

It looks like HQL guesses a parameter to be an int if you don't specify it and then you get a conversion error. 

Could it be that HQL doesn't like the limit parameter, or, do you have data that when  CONCAT(title, ' ', description) occurs, results in your string starting with ace ?

Comment: I replaced `CONCAT(title, ' ', description)` with just `description` and it didn't change anything (btw, whad did you mean by "starting with ace"? Did you mean "asterisk"?), the testing String data is alpha-numeric with spaces, nothing else. The limit parameter is generated by the "pageable magic" and I don't have any control over it. 
I will try to run it through Postgres database to find out if it's just H2's problem.

Comment: Starting with ace - ie this string "aced00057......."

In other words, any titles in your db that when concatentated with description start with "aced00057" ?

May well be an HQL funny,

Comment: Please verify that you get the same error when connecting to actual Postgres instance, this error may be related to unimplemented feature in H2.

Comment: And yes, it is working with Postgresql, so the problem is with H2. Now there is still a question on why H2 is not happy, but at least I see where the problem is. What should I do for the question? Update it? Provide an answer with "The problem is with H2"?

Comment: ORDER BY <some bind parameter> works in Postgres? Color me surprised.

Comment: AFAIK you need some SQL hackery to have a dynamic Order By. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/8139871/66686