# Spring JPA hibernate query builder

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I just wanted to create query dynamically.Means I just wanted to specify in which column the sorting will occure and type sorting as `ASC or DESC` also with this query i have to limit the no of records. I am using the **PostgreSQL** here. So in the query i should specify the **limit and offset** .

So that i am sending the four variable in the sense attribute to the interface.

**WorkflowDetailsInterface.java**

```
@Configuration
public interface WorkflowDetailsInterface extends CrudRepository<WorkflowDetails, Integer> {
@Query(value ="SELECT workflow_id, workflow_name, workflow_description, workflow_definition, "
        + "camunda_workflow_json, camuda_deployment_id, camunda_status,diagnostic_flag, "
        + "active, del_flag  FROM workflow  ORDER BY :orderByColoumn  : orderByOrder LIMIT  :recordCountLimit OFFSET :startLimit",nativeQuery = true)
    List<WorkflowDetails> listWorkflowName(@Param("startLimit") int startLimit,
            @Param("recordCountLimit")int recordCountLimit,@Param("orderByColoumn")String orderByColoumn,
            @Param("orderByOrder")String orderByOrder);
}
```

Here ,
`@Param("startLimit") int startLimit` will be the starting point
`@Param("recordCountLimit")int recordCountLimit` this is the offset
`@Param("orderByColoumn")String orderByColoumn` order by column name
`@Param("orderByOrder")String orderByOrder` order by type **ASC** or **DESC**

How can i dynamically bind these variable to my JPA query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use stored procedures inside PostgreSQL and pass the parameter mentioning which column to sort and pass Limit parameter to it. Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139618/postgresql-parameterized-order-by-limit-in-table-function) for more info.

You can call the stored procedure like this:

```
String sql ="call <stored_procedure_name>(:parameter1)";
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createNativeQuery(sql).addEntity(<your persistant>.class).setParameter("parameter1", <your param>);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending `CrudRepository` extend `PagingAndSortingRepository`. '[findAll](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html#findAll-org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable-)' method serves your purpose. [PageRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html) is an implementation of [Pageable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html). You can specify limit, offset and sort details. Check this [article](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-repositories) to know more about usage. You may not need native query with this approach.