# parameterize asc vs desc sort in postgres sql

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I want to allow sort to parameterized in a query, field id and order

so I have `select .... order by @sortcol`

then what? How to I use a parameter to indicate asc vs desc?

Using c# npgsql library.

Comment: What is the context? What language/library/... are you using to talk to the database? You generally can't use placeholders for identifiers and SQL language elements so you're probably left with string manipulation.

Comment: @muistooshort updated question

Comment: Easiest way is to add Order By clause with string concatenation or use stored procedure. Here someone had similiary question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139618/postgresql-parameterized-order-by-limit-in-table-function