# POSTGRESQL limit a resulting query given a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, limit, .when

Is there a way in POSTGRESQL to limit a resulting query given a condition?

I have tried something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
LIMIT CASE 
       WHEN extract(hour from now())=9 then 143
       WHEN extract(hour from now())=10 then 178 ETC.`
```

I need to use this because depending on the current hour and the hour in the table, dinamically limit with the condition.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: What you wrote should work. What's the issue?

Comment: Without an ORDER BY the LIMIT makes little sense.

Comment: @eurotrash gives me the following error: SQL Error [4856] [42601] Syntax error.  `LIMIT CASE WHEN extract(hour from now())=11 and replace(to_char(now(),'day'),' ','')='thursday' then 109 end`

Comment: @joop I have an order by clause.

Comment: you probably look for function that returns query?.. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139618/postgresql-parameterized-order-by-limit-in-table-function

Comment: @ecp it works fine for me: `SELECT *
FROM generate_series(1, 10) g
LIMIT CASE WHEN extract(hour from now())=11 and replace(to_char(now(),'day'),' ','')='thursday' then 109 ELSE 4 end` returns 4 items.

Comment: @VaoTsun yes, everything that returns a result depending on day and hour, and limiting it depending on the day and hour.

Comment: @eurotrash the same you wrote give me this: SQl Error [4256] Only reltaions and subqueries are allowed in the FROM clause.

Comment: It looks like a Vertica problem. Maybe I could try to use a rank or something else.

Comment: Wait a minute - Vertica? Why did you use the PostgreSQL tag then?

Comment: You can't have a LIMIT clause that changes for every row. It's unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve. Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ?) as seqnum
      FROM table t
     ) t
WHERE (extract(hour from now()) = 9 AND seqnum <= 143) OR
      (extract(hour from now()) = 10 AND seqnum <= 178) OR
      . . .
```

The more likely solution would be to handle this at the application layer.

Note the `?`:  this represents the column to use for ordering the data.  Normally when using `LIMIT`, you want `ORDER BY`.

Comment: yes, I think this is the best I can do, even with a `CASE` statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-limit.html

> LIMIT { number | ALL }

you can't use expression here, like you do with `ORDER BY`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-order.html

> ORDER BY sort_expression1 [ASC | DESC] [NULLS { FIRST | LAST }]
>                [, sort_expression2 [ASC | DESC] [NULLS { FIRST | LAST }] ...]

you need dynamic SQL here, for examplelook at [PostgreSQL parameterized Order By / Limit in table function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139618/postgresql-parameterized-order-by-limit-in-table-function)