# Not 100% sure if this is safe

Tags: postgresql

Given the following PostgreSQL code, I think that this code is not vulnerable to SQL injection:

```
_filter 'day'
_start 1
_end 10
_sort 'article_name'
_order 'ASC'

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE '
SELECT *
FROM articles a
WHERE article_name ILIKE ''%' || $1 || '%''
ORDER BY $4 ' || $5 || '
LIMIT ($3-$2) OFFSET $2'
USING _filter, _start, _end, _sort, _order;
```

But I don't find that much documentation on the `USING` clause in combination with strings. I did find this nice article (accepted answer) on DBA: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159424/how-to-use-function-parameters-in-dynamic-sql-with-execute which I think I've implemented correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code won't do what you want.

`$1` will be replaced with the first **function argument**, **not** with `_filter`.

Also, this is open to SQL injection.

This is what you want:

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
   format(
      E'SELECT *\n'
      'FROM articles a\n'
      'WHERE article_name ILIKE %L\n'
      'ORDER BY %I %s\n'
      'LIMIT %s OFFSET %s',
      '%' || _filter || '%',
      _sort,
      _order,
      _end - _start,
      _start);
```

Comment: mhmm... $3 doesn't "reacts" to sort, see this sample code: 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_articles(_filter VARCHAR, _start INTEGER, _end INTEGER, _sort VARCHAR, _order VARCHAR)
RETURNS SETOF aarticles
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE '
  SELECT a.article_id as id, a.article_name
  FROM aarticles a
  WHERE article_name ILIKE ''%'' || $1 || ''%''
  ORDER BY $3 ' || _order || '
  LIMIT (' || (_end - _start) || ') OFFSET $2'
    USING _filter, _start, _sort;
END;
$$;
SELECT * FROM get_all_articles('c', 0, 10, 'article_id', 'DESC');
kinda lost...

Comment: And the table statement... 
CREATE TABLE aarticles (article_id INT, article_name VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO aarticles(article_id, article_name) VALUES (1, 'bike'), (2, 'car'), (3, 'aircraft');

Comment: I don't understand. Maybe you could open a second question with the new code and a description of your problem.

Comment: I've replaced the ORDER BY with this: 
ORDER BY ' || quote_ident(_sort) || ' ' || _order || ' 
and now it work's as expected. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139618/postgresql-parameterized-order-by-limit-in-table-function/8146245#8146245) For now I've withdrawn the accepted answer, I think that the correction is fair?

Comment: Yes. I have fixed the answer.