# Give a user permission to ALTER a function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, privileges

I try to `ALTER` a function with a new user and I get the error:

```
ERROR:  must be owner of function ACases
********** Error **********

ERROR: must be owner of function ACases
SQL state: 42501
```

What permission do I have to give to a user so he can `ALTER` that function?
The only way I found was to make the user the `OWNER` of the function.

But if that is the case, only one user (owner) can `ALTER` the function. So how would I change the `OWNER` for all functions?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."ACases"(caseid integer)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
        RETURN FALSE;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
ALTER FUNCTION public."ACases"(integer) OWNER TO postgres;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION public."ACases"(integer) TO user_name;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [manual on `ALTER FUNCTION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-alterfunction.html) is clear on that:

> **You must own the function to use `ALTER FUNCTION`.** To change a function's
>   schema, you must also have `CREATE` privilege on the new schema.
>   To alter the owner, you must also be a direct or indirect
>   member of the new owning role, and that role must have `CREATE`
>   privilege on the function's schema. (These restrictions enforce that
>   altering the owner doesn't do anything you couldn't do by dropping and
>   recreating the function. However, a superuser can alter ownership of
>   any function anyway.)

Bold emphasis mine.
You also need a couple of basic privileges to create functions. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html)

> To be able to define a function, the user must have the `USAGE`privilege on the language.
>   ...
>
> To be able to create a function, you must have `USAGE` privilege on the argument types and the return type.

The simple solution would be make changes to functions **as superuser**. (Default superuser is `postgres`, but any user *can* be made superuser.)

**If** you really need to change ownership on all functions, this would do the trick:

```
SELECT string_agg('ALTER FUNCTION '
            || quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.' 
            || quote_ident(p.proname) || '(' 
            || pg_catalog.pg_get_function_identity_arguments(p.oid)
            || ') OWNER TO foo;'
          , E'\n') AS _sql
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_proc p
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
WHERE  n.nspname = 'public';
-- AND p.relowner <> (SELECT oid FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'foo')
-- AND p.proname ~~ 'f_%'
```

Restricted to the `public` schema.
For more details and explanation refer to [this more complete answer on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9708/is-there-a-means-to-set-the-owner-of-all-objects-in-a-postgresql-database-at-the).
Also closely related:
[DROP FUNCTION without knowing the number/type of parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622908/drop-function-without-knowing-the-number-type-of-parameters/7623246#7623246)

Comment: Wow Erwin thank you very much. Very clear and detailed. The other day i give up and make that user owner of the function. Now i know what was the problem.