# Remove all data from table but last N entries

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2, postgresql-9.2

I'm using psycopg2 with Python.

I'd like to periodically flush data from my db.  I've set up a task with `Timer` for this.  I had asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712239/psql-how-to-flush-database-content-without-dropping-table) before, but using the answer listed there freezes up my machine (keyboard stops responding and entire system grinds to halt).  Instead, I would like to delete all entries in my table albeit the last N (Not sure that this is the right approach either).

Basically, there is another python process that is running (separate executable), which is populating the db that I wish to interrogate.  It seems that if I delete all entries, and that other process is running, that it can lead to the freeze.  I don't know of a safe way in which I can remove entries; it's almost as if the other process is relying on an incrementing ID as it writes to the db.

If anyone could help me work this out it'd be greatly appreciated. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably much faster:

```
CRETE TEMP TABLE tbl_tmp AS
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY <undisclosed> LIMIT <N>;

TRUNCATE TABLE tbl;
INSERT INTO tbl SELECT * FROM tbl_tmp;
```

Do it all in *one session*. Specifics depend on additional circumstances you did not disclose.

Compare to this related, comprehensive answer (your case is simpler):
[Remove duplicates from table based on multiple criteria and persist to other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717674/remove-duplicates-from-table-based-on-multiple-criteria-and-persist-to-other-tab/15717892#15717892)

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to run a `DELETE` on all ids except those returned by `select ... order by pk desc limit N` given an autoincremental pk. If no such pk exists, having a `created_date` and ordering by it should do the same.

Non tested example:

```
import psycopg2
connection = psycopg2.connect('dbname=test user=postgres')
cursor = conn.cursor()

query = 'delete from my_table where id not in (
            select id from my_table order by id desc limit 30)'
cursor.execute(query)
cursor.commit() #Don't know if necessary
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: Thanks.  Could you give me an example?

Comment: how often would you call cursor.close()?

Comment: You only need to execute a single query, so my guess would be only once.

Comment: Actually, the code is run based on a Task, which occurs anywhere from 1-3 seconds apart on a Timer.  I can get the system to run the Task around 3 times and then my machine freezes up.  I think that the process which is propagating the data (also python) is looking to insert into an ID which now doesn't exist, as we've deleted it.  Possible?

Comment: I just had a thought - is there a way to get Postgres to reset the ID on that table?  I think it's being auto-generated.

Comment: Resetting the ID (i.e., "starting over from 0") is almost **always** a sign of bad design. You should leave those those details to the engine, and find the error in your code. Making the DDBB work around faulty code is asking for trouble.

Comment: I figured out that I wasn't committing, which was causing a disconnect between the two programs.