# Passing table names in an array

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, sql-delete

I need to do the same deletion or purge operation (based on several conditions) on a set of tables. For that I am trying to pass the table names in an array to a function. I am not sure if I am doing it right. Or is there a better way?

I am pasting just a sample example this is not the real function I have written but the basic is same as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test (tablename text[]) RETURNS int AS
$func$
BEGIN

execute 'delete  * from  '||tablename;
  RETURN 1;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But when I call the function I get an error:

```
select test( {'rajeev1'} );

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 10: select test( {'rajeev1'} );
                      ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "{"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 179
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used wrong syntax for `text array constant` in the function call. But even if it was right, your function is not correct.

If your function has `text array` as argument you should loop over the array to execute query for each element.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test (tablenames text[]) RETURNS int AS
$func$
DECLARE
    tablename text;
BEGIN
    FOREACH tablename IN ARRAY tablenames LOOP
        EXECUTE FORMAT('delete  * from  %s', tablename);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN 1;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You can then call the function for several tables at once, not only for one.

```
SELECT test( '{rajeev1, rajeev2}' );
```

If you do not need this feature, simply change the argument type to `text`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test (tablename text) RETURNS int AS
$func$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('delete  * from  %s', tablename);
    RETURN 1;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT test('rajeev1');
```

I recommend using [the **format** function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT).

---

If you want to execute a function (say `purge_this_one_table(tablename)`) on a group of tables identified by similar names you can use this construction:

```
create or replace function purge_all_these_tables(mask text)
returns void language plpgsql 
as $$
declare
    tabname text;
begin
    for tabname in
        select relname 
        from pg_class
        where relkind = 'r' and relname like mask
    loop
        execute format(
            'purge_this_one_table(%s)',
            tabname);
    end loop;
end $$;

select purge_all_these_tables('agg_weekly_%');
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Array syntax

`'{rajeev1, rajeev2}'` or `ARRAY['rajeev1', 'rajeev2']`. [Read the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS)

#### `TRUNCATE`

Since you are deleting all rows from the tables, consider `TRUNCATE` instead. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-delete.html)

> **Tip:** [`TRUNCATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-truncate.html) is a PostgreSQL extension that provides a faster
>   mechanism to remove all rows from a table.

Be sure to study the details. If `TRUNCATE` works for you, the whole operation becomes very simple, since the command accepts multiple tables:

```
TRUNCATE rajeev1, rajeev2, rajeev3, ..
```

#### Dynamic `DELETE`

Else you need dynamic SQL like you already tried. The scary missing detail: you are completely open to **SQL injection** and catastrophic syntax errors. Use [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) with **`%I`** (not `%s` to sanitize identifiers like table names. Or, better yet in this particular case, use an array of `regclass` as parameter instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_del_all(_tbls regclass)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _tbl regclass;
BEGIN
   FOREACH _tbl IN ARRAY _tbls LOOP
      EXECUTE format('DELETE * FROM %s', _tbl);
   END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_del_all('{rajeev1,rajeev2,rajeev3}');
```

Explanation here:
[Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
select test('{rajeev1}');
```