# Clear postgresql and alembic and start over from scratch

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

Everything I found about this via searching was either wrong or incomplete in some way. So, how do I:

- delete everything in my postgresql database
- delete all my alembic revisions
- make it so that my database is 100% like new

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do this without dropping your migration files the steps are:

1. Drop all the tables in the db that are to be recreated.
2. Truncate the alembic_version table (so it will start from the beginning) - this is where the most recent version is kept.

The you can run:

```sh
alembic upgrade head
```

and everything will be recreated. I ran into this problem when my migrations got in a weird state during development and I wanted to reset alembic. This worked.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

1) Access your session, in the same way you did session.create_all, do session.drop_all.

2) Delete the migration files generated by alembic.

3) Run session.create_all and initial migration generation again.

Answer (score 1):

No idea how to mess with alembic, but for the database, you can just log into the SQL console and use `DROP DATABASE foo`.

Or were you wanting to clear out all the data, but leave the tables there?  If so, [Truncating all tables in a postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829158/truncating-all-tables-in-a-postgres-database) has some good answers.