# how to restore a postgresql database to the exact same state?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I am trying to

1. create a snapshot of a PostgreSQL database (using `pg_dump`),
2. do some random tests, and
3. restore to the exact same state as the snapshot, and do some other random tests.

These can happen over many/different days. Also I am in a multi-user environment where I am not DB admin. In particular, I cannot create new DB.

However, when I restore db using

```
 gunzip -c dump_file.gz | psql my_db
```

changes in step 2 above remain.

For example, if I make a copy of a table:

```
 create table foo1 as (select * from foo);
```

and then restore, the copied table `foo1` remains there.

Could some explain how can I restore to the exact same state as if step 2 never happened?

-- Update --

Following the comments @a_horse_with_no_name, I tried to to use

```
DROP OWNED BY my_db_user
```

to drop all my objects before restore, but I got an error associated with an extension that I cannot control, and my tables remain intact.

```
ERROR:  cannot drop sequence bg_gid_seq because extension postgis_tiger_geocoder requires it
HINT:  You can drop extension postgis_tiger_geocoder instead.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can run a `drop schema ...` or even `drop owned by ...` before restoring the dump

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks. Is there a way to do this in the command line? I need it in a scripting environment. I can drop everything I own, but some structures in my db is created by the admin.

Comment: Sure, just run the drop script using `psql`

Comment: It's a pity you can't create a new DB. Using template DBs is as fast and simple as it gets: `CREATE DATABASE mydb TEMPLATE mytemplate;` http://stackoverflow.com/a/12082038/939860

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove everything that's there by dropping and recreating the database or something like that. pg_dump basically just makes an SQL script that, when applied, will ensure all the tables, stored procs, etc. exist and have their data. It doesn't remove anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PostgreSQL Schemas](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-schemas.html).