# PostgreSQL external transaction feature

Tags: postgresql, testing, automated-tests

I have a big web application and tests which make requests to app running in sandbox. After each test I used to rollback database using `db migrate rollback && db migrate && db seed`. But now after test quantity rised, It takes much time. So, I am looking for feature which can wrap some amount of database command into a transaction and after test finish cancel transaction **without modifying app source code** (or make this by another way). May be there are some postgres database parameters or extensions?

Answer (score 0):

I found another way..
I can make a dump one time and then drop and restore dump every time next, much faster)

look this topic:
[Truncating all tables in a Postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829158/truncating-all-tables-in-a-postgres-database)