# Postgres Syntax error when i try to use CONCAT or ||

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql

why am i having syntax error when i try to execute this:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE   CONCAT(' schemaExample.','nameTable ') CONTINUE IDENTITY RESTRICT;
```

Thanks

Comment: You can simply write the `schemaExaple.nameTable` if this is the actual names instead of `CONCAT(' schemaExample.','nameTable ')`

Comment: thank you for the answer, but litterly i will make a loop and call it from java native query  , where schemaExaple will be a parametere and i will loop over sevral table names. Thats why i'm trying this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truncating all tables in a Postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829158/truncating-all-tables-in-a-postgres-database)

Comment: thank you for the answer its very halpfull, but im still wondering why simple truncate table with concate don't work on pgAdmin

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an expression or parameter for an identifier like a table nane. Besides, `TRUNCATE` does not support parameters at all.

You will have to issue two SQL statements and construct the `TRUNCATE` statement from the first one.

Comment: Thank you man for the answer, could you please give a example of what you are saying ?

Comment: What is unclear about my answer? I won't write your. code; look for "dynamic SQL" in the documentation and use `format` to avoid SQL injection.